# Unable to Run Android Application on Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm just a beginner in Android Development.
I'm Creating my First app by Watching Tutorial.
When i try to run my application it throws an error.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'HelloAndroid'.
sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
```

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.<init>(SignedJarBuilder.java:177)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:446)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:422)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:362)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.finalPackage(BuildHelper.java:391)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.finalDebugPackage(BuildHelper.java:359)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:846)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2292)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1143)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$2.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1224)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder cannot be found by com.android.ide.eclipse.base_23.0.7.2120684
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 23 more
```

I have tried Almost Every Solution i found on Web.
but all i found is for old version eclipse.

Here i'm Using,
Windows 7
Java SE 16
Eclipse IDE 2021-03 (4.19.0)

If Someone has any Solution for my Configuration then Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: as you already said you started learning Android, I would suggest you to please use Android Studio and also refer to tutorial those are referring to Android studio.

Comment: Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for a long time now, you should use Android Studio.

Comment: That specific error is because `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder` does not exist in newer versions of Java, you would have to use an older Java to get it (I believe Java 8 was the last to have it)

Comment: Use [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.html) instead of `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder` and take tutorials that are older than a year or two with a huge grain of salt --- they may teach obsolete ideas.